# How to Test cmp() in PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I have started writing tests in PHP just recently and now I have come across a scenario I dont know how to test for.

The comparing function of cmp

```
private function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return max($a->getValue(), $b->getValue());
}
```

And the function that callls it.

```
public function getCredits() 
{
    usort($this->credits, [$this, "cmp"]);
    return $this->credits;
}
```

The credits property is an array of Object that when getValue() is called returns a `float`.

Im using PHPUnit in a Laravel/Homestead environment.

Firstly, its private, so cant be called directly, I suppose I will have to use a reflection class.
Secondly, cmp() is called by PHP and usort().

Any advice will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `cmp` is a private method, you normally wouldn't test it directly. Instead, you test `getCredits` and verify that the credits are returned in the correct order.

The idea behind this is that the unit test is just another "client" (or "user" or "consumer") of the public API of your classes. The goal of the unit tests is to make sure that the external behavior of your classes (the things you can make it do through public methods) are correct. Just like any other client, the unit test doesn't need to know exactly *how* that external behavior is internally implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't test private methods, in such case, your tests should look something like this:

```
$model = new Model([1,6,4,3]);
$this->assertEquals([1,3,4,6], $model->getCredits());

$model = new Model([0,0,4,2,4]);
$this->assertEquals([0,0,2,4,4], $model->getCredits());
```

Obviously in your case instead of plain numbers you should pass objects and your `cmp` function seems to be wrong because normally it should return -1 and 1 and yours will return for example 10 or 20